# Kendo UI Grid Template error - invalid template

Tags: javascript, css, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

```
# if( #:AllTemplateID# == @(ViewBag.BigTemplateID) ) { 
    <div class="templateItem testing" id="#:AllTemplateID#">
        <img src="@(ViewBag.TemplateImageThumbURL)#:AllTemplateUrlImage#" alt="#:AllTemplateName#"/>
    </div>
#} else { #
    <div class="templateItem" id="#:AllTemplateID#">
        <img src="@(ViewBag.TemplateImageThumbURL)#:AllTemplateUrlImage#" alt="#:AllTemplateName#"/>
    </div>
#} #
```

It's saying I have an invalid template. Why? I'm assuming it has something to do with the hashtags - #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first line:

```
# if( #:AllTemplateID# == @(ViewBag.BigTemplateID) ) {
```

First, there is no ending '#' at the end of the line.
Second, you don't need to put hashes around variables `#:AllTemplateID#` if they are already in javascript portions of the template.

Try:

```
# if( AllTemplateID == @(ViewBag.BigTemplateID) ) { #
```

-or-

```
# if( data.AllTemplateID == @(ViewBag.BigTemplateID) ) { #
```